# Error upgrading from 20.04.4 LTS to 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04, do-release-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade, but I encounter errors.
I initiate the upgrade with sudo `do-release-upgrade`, and it goes smooth till 98%. Then I get this error with a detached terminal:

```
2022-08-16 10:57:21,415 DEBUG Installing 'linux-generic' (linux metapackage may have been accidentally uninstalled)
2022-08-16 10:57:21,779 ERROR not handled exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9ycgla6n/jammy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9ycgla6n/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 241, in main
    if app.run():

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9ycgla6n/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2042, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9ycgla6n/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1991, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.calcDistUpgrade():

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9ycgla6n/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1100, in calcDistUpgrade
    if not self.cache.installTasks(self.tasks):

AttributeError: 'DistUpgradeController' object has no attribute 'tasks'
```

Exploring the apt.log, I found a bunch of broken packages as:

```
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 55
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 55
Investigating (0) gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 -> 42.2-0ubuntu0.2 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Breaks on gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons:amd64 < 20.04.0-3~ubuntu20.04.6 @ii mK > (< 21.04)
```

or about `libinvidia-470` :

```
Investigating (0) libnvidia-compute-470:amd64 < 470.141.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libnvidia-compute-470:amd64 Conflicts on libcuda-10.0-1:amd64 < none @un H >
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for libnvidia-compute-515-server but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for libnvidia-compute-515 but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Conflicts//Breaks against version 510.85.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for libnvidia-compute-510-server but that is not InstVer, ignoring
  Considering libnvidia-compute-510:amd64 3 as a solution to libnvidia-compute-470:amd64 4
  Added libnvidia-compute-510:amd64 to the remove list
```

full [main.log](https://fastupload.io/en/ply9Z0Qx1XoR6XS/file) and [apt.log](https://fastupload.io/en/ZuP7IcdwWTNS5uD/file) are available.

My machine has:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64;
Kernel: 5.15.0-46-generic;
Packages: 3896 (dpkg), 34 (snap);
Shell: bash 5.0.17;
DE: GNOME;
DM: Wayland;
WM: Mutter;
Terminal: gnome-terminal;
CPU: Intel i7-4910MQ (8) @ 2.900GHz;
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 730M;
GPU: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor;
Memory: 4180MiB / 15879MiB.

Thank you for any input!

EDIT: correction of a command.

Comment: Do you mean `do-release-upgrade`? I'm not aware of any command called `do-distro-upgrade`.

Comment: It seems a confirmed bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1969786

Comment: Having the same issue.

Comment: A fix has been released, but I am still experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

```
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall distro-info
sudo apt reinstall python3-distro-info
```

Also check this bug report: [do-release-upgrade fails 19.10->20.04 AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'version'](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1874250)